# Is there a way to have a rotation percentage on an object?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Per the GIF below, as you can see as I increase/decrease the window size the image on the left grows and shrinks as it 's supposed to. What I've done is include the line inside of the "image wrapper" that I have set up. My goal here is when the image shrinks I have the line line up with its respected block of text you see on the right. Right now I have the line positioned as `absolute` with percentage values for `left` and `top`. Is there a way to adjust the rotation of the line for what I'm trying to accomplish? How can I get that line to line up with the title no matter what? Are percentages possible for rotation? (I don't think so)

This raises one concern of mine. Sure, a CSS only solution would be great, but the concern is compatibility with browsers. If the solution can be in JavaScript that would be just as perfect, but I wouldn't know where to start with something like this for JS.

Any other suggestions are welcome.

GIF Example:
[image]

Code example used: https://jsfiddle.net/01sxrjkr/ *Make sure the preview window is <768px

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Added jsFiddle link for reference of what I'm using.

Comment: Found this: codepen.io/rafaysaeedansari/pen/KdmybR but it uses GSS. I'm not too familiar with it. What's the browser compliance for something like that? EDIT: I've read that GSS is a performance nightmare so this solution probably goes out the window...

Comment: @EugeneRoss What Paulie was saying is that you have to include the actual code in the question. Links to code sandboxes are not acceptable on their own.

Comment: There is no need for percentages of rotation as degrees are already a percentage of sorts.  The amount of rotation is finite and never changes.  It's always 360 degrees possible, so 360=100%, 180=50%, and so on.

Comment: Even if you did come up with a js solution that would adjust the rotation based on the width of the column, you still wouldn't achieve what you are hoping for since the height of the column on the right doesn't change consistently along with the change of width.  It's height is reliant on when each line of text wraps which of course is based on the length of the last word in each line.

Comment: @ChrisM thanks for the reply. So I take that there probably isn't a solution to make this "perfect?" I can get close with media queries, which is fine. Now I'm just more curious if there's even a way to have something like this line up how I would've liked it :)

Answer (score 0):

You are rotating from the wrong end of the line.   Try this instead, then just use media queries to alter the number of rotation degrees in relation to the text on the right for each of the most common media widths.  Remember, people don't go around re-sizing their screens, so having it perfect at every single pixel of width is unnecessary and really not possible with what you have going on there.  You're image is responsive and your text, of course, is not.  therefor as the width of the screen is reduced, your left column decreases in height as your image gets smaller while your right column increases in height as more text wraps.

```
.line.line-1 {
    left: 62%;
    top: 39%;
    transform: rotate(14deg);
    width: 40%;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. So if I were to use media queries to get it as close as possible, it seems like I would have one for every 10px to change the positioning, right?

Comment: 3 or 4 queries would be enough.   I think there are probably better options for your end goal.  height is not really responsive through css and for that matter any means.  if you think about it, there is not really any bottom to a webpage until you get to the end of the content without setting a fixed height.  and the fixed height squashes all attempts at being responsive.   there are klunky workarounds but your better bet is to think of another way of conveying your content.